# "Unexpected end of form" error while uploading image in JMeter

Tags: file-upload, jmeter

In the application, there is a functionality named "Add Organization" and there is an option to upload the logo of the organization. I have recorded the script and when I playback it, I am getting the error "{"message":"Unexpected end of form"}".

Can anybody help me in solving this problem?

I have tried by giving the file path in Parameters, Body and even File Upload.

Answer (score 0):

If you're recording a file upload event using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) you need to remember one simple rule:

**Copy the file you're going to upload to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation** before executing the associated request

This way JMeter will be able to properly capture the request and generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)

Comment: Tried this, but not working. The image file is being sent as binary. First the image in uploaded to amazon S3 and the the unique url from there is passed in the api.